# how to fill this gap?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: The gap in this model.]

How can I fill this gap for the model? I am asking specifically for this one because it will help me troubleshoot other ones I will make when I come to this problem again.

so, what's the best way to fill this gap?

Comment: Hello. It is not totally clear. Where the selected part supposed to be linked to? Where is the "gap" (the 'hole', the selected part extremity, other)?

Comment: Also please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon

The gap is between the part I have selected. I would like to fix the gap that occurs inside it, but I don't know what the best way is.

Comment: And why would you want to fill it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth When I model something, I almost always come across this issue, where I have to fill the gap to finish the model. If I manage to fix this, the problem will probably not be caused anymore, so I need help fixing the gap in this specific.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you ask about the right topology. If so it's not good that you have inconsistent mesh (by one axis you have far more loop cuts compare to another). If there is a reason for that I would probably fill it like that:
[image]

The big N-gon in the middle is fine if this area is flat.

But the better solution would be to have more consistent mesh so you can connect loops organically. You'll still have 1 triangle but that is fine.

[image]

I hope it helps!